# How to solve the problem of dynamic rowspan problem in table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I am trying to show the table like below image**
[image]
And i write the logic for this table creation is below

```
 @foreach($users as $key => $user)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
              <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
              <td rowspan="{{count($users->where('area',$user->area))}}">
                 {{$user->userarea->name}}</td>

              <td rowspan="{{count($user->candidate->election->candidates)}}">{{$user->candidate->election->name}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
             </tbody>
```

But this code produce me the following code like this
[image]
Here The **Election and Candidate has one to many relationships and candidate and user has one one to one relationship**Help me achieve my expected results.

Comment: I would use css grid

Comment: Can you show an example for this case??

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of which elections/area's have been rendered already. This could be done by creating an array containing a reference to these objects. Then in the template just add an if statement checking whether an election/area has been rendered:

```
<?php $renderedElections = []; ?>
<?php $renderedAreas = []; ?>
@foreach($users as $key => $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    @if (!in_array($user->userarea->name, $renderedAreas))
        <?php $renderedElections[] = $user->userarea->name ?>
        <td rowspan="{{count($user->userarea->name)}}">
            {{$user->userarea->name}}
        </td>
    @endif
    @if (!in_array($user->candidate->election->name, $renderedElections))
        <?php $renderedElections[] = $user->candidate->election->name ?>
        <td rowspan="{{count($user->candidate->election->candidates)}}">
            {{$user->candidate->election->name}}
        </td>
    @endif
</tr>
```

This is not the best solution, but its simple and easy. For this to work, the users must be sorted perfectly by election and area.

Comment: in your code there was an error "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\online-voting-system\resources\views\candidate\index.blade.php)". So by changing this will work. So i edited yours

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested but should theorethically work. I tryied to gather informations about your model relationships from the code you posted, but it might need some tweaking with the model names and relations.

The following code basically fetches all the users each with their `area`, `candidate` and `candidate.election` relationships, then group users by 'election name' (first criteria), then 'area name' (second criteria).

The resulting array will be something like this:

```
// $elections will be:
// [
//      'Presidential' => [
//          'Dhaka-5' => [ candidates for that area in that election type ],
//          'Dhaka-1' => [ candidates for that area in that election type ],
//          ...
//      ],
//      ...
// ]
```

**In your controller do:**

```php
$elections = User::with('area', 'candidate.election')->get()->groupBy(function ($user) {
    return $user->candidate->election->name;
}, function ($user) {
    return $user->area->name;
});

// then pass $elections to the view...
```

**Then in your view:**

```html
<table>
@php ($i = 1)
@foreach ($elections as $election => $areas)
    @foreach ($areas as $area => $candidates)
        @php ($areaLoop = $loop)

        @foreach ($candidates as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                @if ($loop->first)
                    <td rowspan="{{ $candidates->count() }}">{{ $area }}</td>
                @endif

                @if ($areaLoop->first)
                    <td rowspan="{{ $areas->sum(function ($area) { return $area->count(); }); }}">{{ $election }}</td>
                @endif
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</table>
```

Note that `$candidates->count()` will be the number of candidates for that particular election area of the current election type. `$areas->sum(...)` will sum the number of candidates for each area to get the total count of candidates in that election type.

If you need further explaination or something doesn't work, just let me know. All the documentation about the collection functions I used is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby).

Comment: it says "Trying to get property 'election' of non-object" on this line "return $user->candidate->election->name";